# Using React hooks with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

If I have a state in reducer in Redux, should I have a 'local' state in a function component? Or I only should use a state from reducer?
More clearly... If I am using Redux should I use React hooks like (useState)?

Comment: So When i need a state which be use for more than one component, I should write this state in reducer and state which be use for only one component should be write in a that component not in the reducer?

Comment: The last statement is true. The first statement, not always. There are more ways to pass data between components (such as [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), props propagation).

Answer (score 0):

There is no “right” answer for this. Some users prefer to keep every single piece of data in Redux, to maintain a fully serializable and controlled version of their application at all times. Others prefer to keep non-critical or UI state, such as “is this dropdown currently open”, inside a component's internal state.

Using local component state is fine. As a developer, it is your job to determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each piece of state should live. Find a balance that works for you, and go with it.

Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux:

- Do other parts of the application care about this data?
- Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this
  original data?
- Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
- Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given
  point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
- Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's
  already there instead of re-requesting it)?
- Do you want to keep this data consistent while hot-reloading UI
  components (which may lose their internal state when swapped)?

Reference:
https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27528627)

Comment: @рüффп Thank you for your feedback. Edited to include essential parts.